# problem with re index dataframe (dealing with categorical data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

i have a data that look like this

```
subject_id      hour_measure       urine color        heart_rate
3                 1                  red                40
3                 1.15               red                 60
4                  2                  yellow             50
```

i want to re index data to make 24 hour of measurement for every patient
 i use the following code

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,24)],
                                  names=['subject_id','hour_measure'])
df = df.groupby(['subject_id','hour_measure']).mean().reindex(mux).reset_index()
df.to_csv('totalafterreindex.csv')
```

it works good with numeric values , but with categorical values it removed it ,
how can i enhance this code to use mean for numeric and most frequent for categorical

the wanted output

```
 subject_id      hour_measure       urine color        heart_rate
    3                 1                  red                40
    3                 2                  red                 60
    3                 3                  yellow             50  
    3                 4                  yellow             50  
    ..                ..                ..
```

Comment: " but with categorical values it removed it". What is "it"?

Comment: i mean  with this code , the string values removed ( in my data set , it removed columns contain text , like urine color )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `mean` for numeric and `mode` for categorical, also is added `next` with `iter` for return `None`s if `mode` return empty value:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,24)],
                                  names=['subject_id','hour_measure'])
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x.mode()), None)
df1 = df.groupby(['subject_id','hour_measure']).agg(f).reindex(mux).reset_index()
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['subject_id','hour_measure']).agg(f))
                        urine color  heart_rate
subject_id hour_measure                        
3          1.00                 red          40
           1.15                 red          60
4          2.00              yellow          50
```

Last if necessary forward filling missing values per `subject_id` use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['subject_id','hour_measure'])
df[cols] = df.groupby('subject_id')[cols].ffill()
```