# re index for both numeric and text column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

i am in python i have data frame that contains both numeric and text columns like this

```
subject_id   hour_measure urinecolor blood pressure  
    1          1.00        red             40           
    1          1.15        red           high          
    2          2.00     yellow            low          
    2          3.00     yellow             20
```

i want to re index data set according to hour measure from 1 to 6 to be like this and for numeric columns but the mean value in hour , and for text columns use the most frequent value to be finally like this

```
subject_id  hour_measure urinecolor blood pressure  
    1          1.00        red             40           
    1          2.00     yellow            low            
    1          3.00     yellow             20           
    1          4.00     yellow             20
```

the following code works correctly with numeric columns , but for text columns it its deleted.

```
df2= pd.read_csv('file path')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,24)],
                                  names=['subject_id','hour_measure'])
df = df.groupby(['subject_id','hour_measure']).mean().reindex(mux).reset_index()
```

how can i update this code to re-index and not delete the text columns

Comment: It seems there is missing column `subject_id`

Comment: How working [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59198842/2901002) solution?

Comment: yes update it to include subject_id